# Rewritting adminhtml block issues

Tags: magento-1, overrides

This is my xml:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <mynamespace_mymodule>
            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
        </mynamespace_mymodule>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <customer_edit_tab_view_accordion>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion</customer_edit_tab_view_accordion>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

This is the php code:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        echo 1;
        exit();
    }
}
```

What did I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep below xml. Try below code,

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <mynamespacemymodule>
            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
        </mynamespacemymodule>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <customer_edit_tab_view_accordion>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion</customer_edit_tab_view_accordion>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Comment: thx for the reply, I did you modification, but still nothing.  :(

Comment: have you change mymodule only inside blocks

Comment: yes , only inside the <blocks>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `mynamespace_mymodule` node:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <customer_edit_tab_view_accordion>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion</customer_edit_tab_view_accordion>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

Also make sure your code is in the folder structure dictated by the class name, i.e., it should be in Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Accordion.php